# Non-matching media query overriding default styles

Tags: css, media-queries

I have looked at similar questions here and did not find a suitable answer, so forgive me that this question may appear at first to be a duplicate of others here.

My screen resolution is 1366px wide

I have default styles, and then several media queries at the end of the stylesheet, in the following order:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1920px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1680px), only screen and (max-device-width: 1680px)  {
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1280px), only screen and (max-device-width: 1280px)  {
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1024px), only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){
}
```

On my machine, the styles from the very first media query (max-width: 1920px) are being applied. When I inspect in Firebug, it gives me the line # coinciding with a declaration within that first media query.

This is happening across several browsers (Firefox, Chrome)

But, my viewport is just 1366px wide - so, I would expect either max-width:1280px or max-width:1680px to match, and not 1920px.

When I resize to 1024x768, or 800x600, the correct media query styles are applied.

What am I doing wrong?

I've looked for any missing bracket closures and found none. I've validated using the W3C CSS validator service, and checked as Correct, no errors found.

Comment: Do you have style values in the `max-width:1680px` that *override* the style values in the `max-width:1920px`?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang Yes. Within each query I define `body, input{ }` font size, `.inner { }` width, and several other class heights. The same style values with varying properties depending on the query

Comment: Can you swap your queries to start from smallest to largest?

Comment: Could you post a fiddle or something please?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang here's a fiddle, trimmed down of course, http://jsfiddle.net/t1mm4tq1/show/

Comment: YES, thank you!! I'm looking at it in Firefox -- media queries are being applied as expected in my browser. It does *reference* the line `max-width:1920px` when my window is less than 1680px, but the styling is not *applied* (the line is crossed out in the Inspector in Firefox).

Comment: @kittykittybangbang peculiar, because for me at 1366px wide it's applying `#feature height: 32em` (only defined this height at `max-width:1920px` media query)

Comment: Ohhhhh, well that's why, silly!! :) Once you define `#feature height` at `max-width:1920px`, it won't change unless you *overwrite it* with one of the subsequent queries. Your 1366px wide screen *does* fall under the category of `max-width:1920px` (it is less than or equal to 1920px), so that `max-width:1920px` block runs. The smaller `max-width`s will overwrite that *if and only if* they explicitly redefine it.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang d'oh! thanks for this explanation :)

Comment: No worries, friend! My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your logic.

Your first query states max-width: 1920px. Indeed, because your desktop is at 1366px, it is smaller than 1920px, so it is a valid query. Consider this a catch all after your 1680px.

I would suggest re-ordering and starting with smallest, most constraining queries first:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1024px), only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1280px), only screen and (max-device-width: 1280px)  {
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1680px), only screen and (max-device-width: 1680px)  {
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1920px) {
}
```

An even better approach would be to use min-width for all of your queries:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px), only screen and (min-device-width: 800px) {
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1024px), only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px)  {
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1280px), only screen and (min-device-width: 1280px)  {
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1680px), only screen and (min-device-width: 1680px)  {
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1920px) {
}
```

As a best practice, here is Bootstraps queries:

```
/*==================================================
=            Bootstrap 3 Media Queries             =
==================================================*/




    /*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

    }



    /*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

    }

    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

    }
```

Comment: But then the next query would be a valid query too, and would *overwrite* the values from the previous query. Right?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang Yes, it depends on what the desired effect is. For best practice, I would advise going with Bootstrap style: https://scotch.io/quick-tips/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries

Comment: Thanks for this, I changed all to min-width and reversed order (so tablet is first, then 800x600, all the way up to 1920px) but now at 1024x768 my 1200x styles are being applied ??

Comment: When I remove `min-device-width` declarations, keeping just `min-width`, this approach appears to work great

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `min-width` not `max-width`. Since you're query is applying to any screen up to `1920px` wide, it is always being applied when your screen is no larger than `1366px` wide. `max-width` == `<=`, `min-width` == `>=`.

```
/* apply these selectors when the width is equal to or greater than 1920px */
@media only screen and (min-width:1920px) {
}
```

Comment: But since they're *cascading* style sheets -- shouldn't the styling written last override what's written beforehand? Although I think OP could have written it more clearly, I don't understand why this would be the issue... ?

Comment: The OP is saying that rules from the 1920px selector are being applied and doesn't understand why if their screen is less than 1920px. It's possible that there may be more going on but without a demo I can't see anything else that might be wrong with it.

Comment: A demo certainly would be helpful -- but did you see the comments b/t OP and me?

Comment: Thanks for this, combined with the other answer, this was the solution. A glaring problem appears to be my use of `min/max-device-width` in addition to `min/max-width`. Clearly I need some additional study here.